# Workstation setup for a developer and gaming enthusiast

Tags: web-development, productivity, gaming, workstation

I found my optimal programming environment and productivity toolset on OS X. My workstation used to be a Macbook Pro that's attached to an external keyboard, mouse, and an external monitor.

Now I just assembled an enthusiast gaming desktop with dual-GPUs, some powerful specs and all, and it's running Windows 7. I have unplugged the monitor/mouse/keyboard from the Macbook Pro so I can use them instead for the gaming desktop (and just do programming a-la laptop style).

I'm wondering how to go about my setup so I can do both programming and gaming, in a "restful" manner. Is it most convenient to just buy another monitor/mouse/keyboard for the Macbook Pro? In that case I'm going to have two desks, i.e. two sets of monitors/mice/keyboards, switching between them for programming and gaming. Isn't this a bit too much?

An alternative would be to only use one monitor and switch the input source between desktop and Macbook. Though the issue that I see here is that I have to plug/unplug my only pair of keyboard and mouse between use. I can buy a second set of mouse and keyboard for convenience, but my desk would look kinda weird.

Any advice? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you buy a switch you only need one keyboard and mouse...